# matlab image uint8 Array, finding top most left/top/bottom/right pixel location

Tags: image-processing, matlab

How is the image data saved with an uint8 array? Say that I have an obscure circular image, instead of a rectangular, so there is no pixel data beyond the circle. How do I go about the top most pixel location? The bottom most? Etc... And this image does not have to be a circle, it could be something obscure and non-geometric.

Comment: You should define the border of your image more clearly. Does it follow some formula?

Comment: @Beginner no, unfortunately it's completely random. I'm using a saliency map which crops out the most salient object in a normal image. Thus, this cropped out image can have any shape imaginable.

Comment: For a more generic answer, please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16985818/376454).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image is loaded into an array of rows x columns x RGB.
Assuming missing pixels are zeros, here are the top/bottom/left/right coordinates:

```
[top_col, top_row]= find(sum(I,3)', 1);
[bottom_col, bottom_row]= find(sum(I,3)', 1, 'last');
[left_row, left_col]= find(sum(I,3), 1);
[right_row, right_col]= find(sum(I,3), 1, 'last');
```

Comment: `find(x,1)` returns the coordinates of the first non-zero after a raster-scan.

Comment: how are these same? i dont think they should be same 
[left_row, left_col]= find(sum(I,3), 1);
[right_row, right_col]= find(sum(I,3), 1, 'last');
and
[top_col, top_row]= find(sum(I,3)', 1);
[bottom_col, bottom_row]= find(sum(I,3)', 1, 'last');

Comment: you are storing the same result i.e. find(sum(I,3)', 1, 'last'); in [bottom_col, bottom_row] and in [right_row, right_col]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `sparse` matrices to store your image.
It will store pixels only at the place you want.

The sparse matrices are stored like that:

- a list of values. `v`
- a list of beginning of columns `c`, such that all values `v(c(i):(c(i+1)-1))` belongs to column `i`
- a list of row indices `r`, such that the row of value `v(j)` is `r(j)`

Comment: This may result in using more space than a full matrix because there is a high ratio of non-zero pixels.

Comment: That is the cost of having an "obscure" image.

Comment: @oli what do you mean? I never edited anything in the question