# How to get the bounding box of non-zero elements in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Let's say, I have a matrix (by [imread](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html)) as following:

```
A = [0 0 1 0 0; 
     0 0 1 0 0; 
     0 1 1 1 0; 
     0 0 1 0 0; 
     0 0 0 0 0];
```

I would like to get the bounding box of non-zero elements as

```
BB = show_me_the_bounding_box(A);
BB = [1, 2, 4, 4]; % y0, x0, y1, x0
```

What function I should use to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result you want, please use:

```
[y,x] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A))
coord = [y, x]
[min(coord) max(coord)] % [1 2 4 4]
```

Note however that, with the correct conventions, the bounding box is:

```
[y,x] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A))
coord = [x, y]
mc = min(coord)-0.5
Mc = max(coord)+0.5
[mc Mc-mc] % [1.5 0.5 3 4]
```

which yields the same result as:

```
stats = regionprops(A, 'BoundingBox')
BB = stats.BoundingBox % [1.5 0.5 3 4]
```

The code can easily be adapted to 3D images, by using:

```
[y,x,z] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A));
coord = [x, y, z];
mc = min(coord)-0.5;
Mc = max(coord)+0.5;
[mc Mc-mc]
```

Comment: I would suggest explicitly defining the dimension `min` and `max` are working in, e.g. `min(coord, [], 1)` otherwise the method will fail when you want to bound a single entry or point.

Answer (score 3):

Use [REGIONPROPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8hf)

```
stats = regionprops(A,'BoundingBox');
BB = stats.BoundingBox;
```

Comment: Interestingly, `regionprops(A, 'BoundingBox')` will return `1.5000    0.5000    3.0000    4.0000`~

Comment: BB contains the origin (1.5 and 0.5) and the width (3 and 4), which gives [1.5 0.5 4.5 4.5] for coordinates, which is correct.